# Android. Data between Activities and Fragment

Tags: android

What is the best practice to get data from an activity to a fragment?

- With a bundle passed as argument
- Making data in activity accessible from fragment with a public method that returns the data

Comment: depends , you have data before or after be specific though google will leads to you similar questions

Comment: bundle is prefered

Answer (score 1):

Pass the data from activity like this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", name);
bundle.putString("address", address);
FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
fragmentA.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment A `onCreateView` method retrieve it like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    String name = getArguments().getString("name");    
    String address = getArguments().getString("address"); 
}
```

**EDIT**

If fragment is already loaded then you can do it like this (using your current implementation)

Send data like this

```
PassDataToFragment fragA = (PassDataToFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container); // Change the id as per yours
fragA.passDataToFragment(name, address);
```

You will get the data in `passDataToFragment()` inside fragment A.

Comment: I know that, but it is not answering my question

Comment: check the last edit please